# can't connect client to server on different computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, client-server

I have a client server application in mfc that sends a message (string) to the server and the server receives the message and also displays the ip address the port used by the client in a text box. i tried running the client exe file on another computer but i get an error message saying can't connect to server. i ran the debug and release exe file so i think the problem is in the code some where.

client code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SocketTestClient.h"
#include "SocketTestClientDlg.h"
#include <string>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CSocketTestClientDlg dialog




CSocketTestClientDlg::CSocketTestClientDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CSocketTestClientDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_senddata(_T(""))
    , m_recvData(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CSocketTestClientDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, m_senddata);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_recvData);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSocketTestClientDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CSocketTestClientDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &CSocketTestClientDlg::OnBnClickedCancel)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CSocketTestClientDlg message handlers

BOOL CSocketTestClientDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CSocketTestClientDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CSocketTestClientDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CSocketTestClientDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CSocketTestClientDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(s == -1)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Socket Initialiation Error");
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN serveraddr;
    struct hostent *hostentry;


    bool bSent = false;
    std::string server = "10.13.32.133";
    int portno = 1818;

    hostentry = gethostbyname(server.c_str());
    char *pipaddr = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr *)*hostentry->h_addr_list);

     memset(&serveraddr,0, sizeof(serveraddr));
     serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(pipaddr);

    //serv_addr.sa_data = htons(portno);

    if (connect(s,(SOCKADDR*)&serveraddr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) < 0) 
    {
         AfxMessageBox("ERROR connecting to the server");
         exit(1);
    }   

    char sbuf[1024], rbuf[1024];

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    sprintf(sbuf,"%s\r\n", (const char*) m_senddata);
    if(send(s, sbuf, strlen(sbuf), 0) == strlen(sbuf))
    {
        recv(s, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        m_recvData = rbuf;
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
    ::closesocket(s);
}


void CSocketTestClientDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{

    OnCancel();
}
```

server code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SocketTestServer.h"
#include "SocketTestServerDlg.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>



#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CSocketTestServerDlg dialog




CSocketTestServerDlg::CSocketTestServerDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CSocketTestServerDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_recvData(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CSocketTestServerDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_recvData);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSocketTestServerDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CSocketTestServerDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &CSocketTestServerDlg::OnBnClickedCancel)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CSocketTestServerDlg message handlers

BOOL CSocketTestServerDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    StartServer();
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CSocketTestServerDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CSocketTestServerDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CSocketTestServerDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CSocketTestServerDlg::StartServer()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN serveraddr;
    int portno = 1818;
    memset(&serveraddr,0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    m_serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(m_serversocket == -1)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Socket Initialiation Error");
    }

    if(bind(m_serversocket, (SOCKADDR*)&serveraddr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) < 0) 
    {
         AfxMessageBox("ERROR binding in the server socket");
         exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(m_serversocket,0) < 0)
    {
         AfxMessageBox("ERROR listening in the server socket");
         exit(1);
    }   

    SetTimer(0x01, 100, NULL);
}

static void f(void *p)
{
    CSocketTestServerDlg *pDlg = reinterpret_cast<CSocketTestServerDlg*>(p);
    pDlg->ProcessClientRequest();
}

void CSocketTestServerDlg::ProcessClientRequest()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN clientaddr;
    struct hostent *hostentry;
    int len = sizeof(clientaddr);
    SOCKET clientsocket = accept(m_serversocket, (sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &len);

    if(len == -1)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Error accpeting the client socket");
    }
    else
    {
        char *p = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
        int portno = ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port);
        // int inet_pton(int af, const char *restrict src, void *restrict dst);

        char rbuf[1024];
        recv(clientsocket, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        for(int i = 1024; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if(rbuf[i] == '\n' && rbuf[i - 1] == '\r')
            {
                rbuf[i-1] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        CString strRecvData;

        strRecvData.Format("%s\r\n%s %d\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", (const char*)CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"), p, portno, rbuf);
        m_recvData += strRecvData;
        m_bRefershData = true;
        strcat(rbuf, "\r\n");
        send(clientsocket, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        closesocket(clientsocket);
    }
}

void CSocketTestServerDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    int idx = nIDEvent;

    if(m_bRefershData == true)
    {
        m_bRefershData = false;
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }

    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int result;
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 100;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(m_serversocket, &fds);

    int rc = select(sizeof(fds)*8, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (rc==-1) 
    {
      AfxMessageBox("ERROR selecting in the server socket");
      return;
    }
    else if(rc > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(m_serversocket, &fds)) 
        {
            m_bRefershData = false;
            HANDLE h = (HANDLE) ::_beginthread(f, 0, (void*) this);
        }

    }        
    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
void CSocketTestServerDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{  

    OnCancel();
}

void CSocketTestServerDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{

    OnOK();
}
```

Comment: Nobody is gonna read that much code. Can you narrow it down??

Comment: Unless someone has absolutely nothing else do do, no one will read  and debug this.

Comment: sorry i just wanted to show everything. i'm guessing the error is around the message AfxMessageBox("ERROR connecting to the server"); in the client code - its near the end. that's the message that get displayed when i run the client on a different computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, look at the description of the error that the client gets. You can do it like this:

```
if (connect(s,(SOCKADDR*)&serveraddr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) < 0) 
{
    CString msg = _T("ERROR connecting to the server: ");
    msg += _com_error(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(WSAGetLastError())).ErrorMessage();
    AfxMessageBox(msg);
    exit(1);
}
```

You need to include comdef.h for the _com_error class.

One likely problem is that the server's computer is connected to the internet through a router of some sort, so it can't act as a server.

Comment: thanks that worked. what does this line do? msg += _com_error(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(WSAGetLastError())).ErrorMessage();

Comment: it formats the last error code of Winsock into a string description of the error

Comment: so if its just describing the error how did it solve my problem?

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, I just suggested that you try it so you can find out why the connection fails! you said that it worked, so, what do you get displayed in the message box now?

Comment: sorry when i said it works i meant that it connected to the server. that's why i'm confused about how that code fixed the problem.

Comment: well it must be something else, because the code I posted doesn't do anything other than formatting the error message and displaying it in case the connection fails

Comment: well it doesn't really matter now since its working. i do have one other question though. every time i send a message from the client to the server, the server displays a different port number. shouldn't a client have the same port number?

Comment: no, the port number that the client uses for the connection is independent of the server's port number